# Keras ConvLSTM2D: ValueError when saving model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create several LSTM models for time series prediction (e.g. Vanilla, Stacked, Bidirectional). After creating a model I want to save it using [tf.keras.models.save_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model)

This works fine for the LSTM architectures I describe above, but when trying to save a [ConvLSTM model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ConvLSTM2D) I get the following error: *ValueError: Object dictionary contained a non-trackable object: (None, None) (for key states)*

I am using Keras with backend TensorFlow (2.X) on a Colab notebook. I've created a [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pBgmoO4LbG_8xsit5FjrzD5GJjGPBkQa) where the problem can be reproduced.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: the model should be saved in the Tensorflow SavedModel format (save_format='tf')

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can save your model.

1. `model.save('model.h5')`
2. Your method but you're missing model name and extension.

Go to gdrive directory using cd.

```
% cd /content/gdrive
```

Save with the file name and extension.

```
# save model to drive
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model = model,
    filepath = 'model2.h5',
    overwrite=True,
    include_optimizer=True,
    save_format=None,
    signatures=None
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my case I need to save the model in the Tensorflow SavedModel format (save_format='tf'). When I try to do this using your suggestion, I still get the same error *ValueError: Object dictionary contained a non-trackable object: (None, None) (for key states)*

Comment: your model can't be serialized with Tensorflow SavedModel, you have to use .h5 or probably have to use a new implmentation in tensorflow suitable for SavedModel.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I can confirm this issue has been fixed in Tensorflow 2.3.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40081